# Bind request mapping to submit input button in html (Springboot)

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

My RequestController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/request")
public class RequestsController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TmtApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    RequestRepository requestRepository;

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    String saveRequest()
    {
        Request requestObj = new Request(usersRepository.findOne(1L), new Date());
        requestObj.setDescription("I got so bored");
        requestObj.setStatus(false);
        requestObj.setRequestDate(new Date());
        requestRepository.save(requestObj);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

My button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Request" style="display: block;">
```

I'm trying to get my button to fire off this request. What should I add to my HTML to initiate the call for /save?

**Update:**

Form:

```
<form action="/request/save" method="post" commandName="requestData">
    <input type="text" id="dateInput" value="" style="display: none;"/>
    <div style="width: 200px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit Request" style="display: block;">
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String saveRequest(@ModelAttribute("requestData") Request requestData, Map<String, Object> map,
                       HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        Request requestObj = new Request(usersRepository.findOne(1L), new Date());
        requestObj.setDescription(requestData.getDescription());
        requestObj.setStatus(false);
        requestObj.setRequestDate(requestData.getRequestDate());
        requestRepository.save(requestObj);
        return "save";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work using the spring code as-is, you must surround your  tag with a form.

```
<form action="save">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Request" style="display: block;">
</form>
```

In addition, you must be calling this from the correct URL to get it to work. The form action can be relative to the page you're on, or relative to the root of the URL.

You have two options to hit the RequestMapping, which resolves to:

```
/request/save
```

One is to use a relative action. You'll have to serve your HTML up at this url:

```
    {server:port}/request
```

and then your action should be:

```
    "save"
```

The second option is to use an absolute path for the form action:

```
    "/request/save"
```

Which will work from wherever your HTML is served on this server.

**Summary**

You need to submit something (the form), and tell it where to submit to (action).  So you need to sync up your URL's, your form, and the submission endpoint.

Additionally, it is a good idea to specify the request method on your RequestMapping so that you can handle POST/GET separately. According to the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping), the default behavior is to map ALL HTTP methods:

> The above example does not specify GET vs. PUT, POST, and so forth,
>   because @RequestMapping maps all HTTP methods by default.

It's a good idea to specify a POST for a form submit.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

This is the direction you should go, since a form submit should be a POST action so that the contents of the form go in the request body, and eventually you will want it to take in fields from your form for the POST, and map them to objects in your Controller class.

**A few Tips:**

Consider using a Templating engine like Thymeleaf (which spring often has in their tutorials), or JSP+taglibs.  Thymeleaf is a bit more lightweight, and if you use it, you'll have the benefit of doing things the way Spring has written a lot of their examples. See this tutorial for an example:

[Spring Boot: Handling Form Submission](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

Alternatively if someone is just trying to test a Request Mapping, or you're just trying to verify that your MVC endpoint is doing what you think, it would be a lot simpler to use a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (which I highly reccomend) to submit your requests.  That would take a few variables out for you so you can focus on what you're trying to develop (A REST API?), rather than the testing setup.

Comment: I've modified my request mapping to be a ``POST`` method. Should the form action be ``save`` or ``request/save``?

Comment: It depends on the URL your HTML is being served at.  You could use "/request/save" (notice the slash prefix) and it will be relative to your root.  I suspect that will work best for you.  Alternatively, if your HTML is served up from /request you can use the relative action of "save"

Comment: the default method is not `GET`. `method` parameter of `@RequestMapping` has no default value which means if you don't narrow method type, it will handle all type of requests.

Comment: Thanks @sedooe.  I'll revise.

Comment: I updated my code. Do you mind taking a look? @JoshHull

Comment: Btw, I'm not using a REST API, rather a local Oracle DB.

Comment: Sure, looks interesting.  Is it working for you? I don't think you need the second two items on your method signature - Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request.  Also, without a taglib, templating engine, or something similar, you're going to have to work hard to keep all the names exactly right to bind the form fields to your object in the Controller method.  Consider using something like Thymleaf or JSP+Taglibs to do this for you.    The spring boot tutorial for this shows a Thymleaf template example, which is pretty nice - https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/